# Backtracking. Begin iteration again from zero in python

Tags: python, iteration

I'm implementing http://ahamnett.blogspot.com/2012/10/funnel-algorithm.html in python.
But the question is about iteration process. How do I start iteration with i = 0 and new lists?

The idea is to iterate through two lists rights and lefts one at a time. Then to measure angle between two points and compare it with the previously calculated angle. If at some time calculated angle becomes larger (funnel widens) I want to begin iteration process again with i = 0 and new rights and lefts lists. 
Currently I'm not getting any output. I think that the problem is with the statement calcu() where I want def calcu() to start over again.

```
import math

def getAngle(a, b, c):
    ang = math.degrees(math.atan2(c[1]-b[1], c[0]-b[0]) - math.atan2(a[1]-b[1], a[0]-b[0]))
    return ang

triangles = [
    [(7, 10), (5, 15), (0, 0)], 
    [(5, 15), (7, 10), (8, 15)], 
    [(12, 10), (8, 15), (7, 10)], 
    [(16, 12), (8, 15), (12, 10)], 
    [(16, 12), (16, 19), (8, 15)], 
    [(8, 24), (8, 15), (16, 19)], 
    [(17, 25), (8, 24), (16, 19)], 
    [(19, 19), (17, 25), (16, 19)], 
    [(19, 19), (40, 19), (17, 25)], 
    [(17, 25), (40, 19), (42, 25)]
]

start = (5, 12)
goal = (33, 22)


def calc(path): 

    rights = [
        (5.0, 15.0), (8.0, 15.0), (8.0, 15.0),
        (8.0, 15.0), (8.0, 15.0), (8.0, 24.0),
        (17.0, 25.0), (17.0, 25.0), (17.0, 25.0)
    ]

    lefts = [
        (7.0, 10.0), (7.0, 10.0), (12.0, 10.0),
        (16.0, 12.0), (16.0, 19.0), (16.0, 19.0),
        (16.0, 19.0), (19.0, 19.0), (40.0, 19.0)
    ]

    rights.append(goal)
    lefts.append(goal)
    rig = rights[0]
    lef = lefts[0]
    node = start
    ang = getAngle(lef, node, rig)
    nodes_list = [node]

    def calcu():
        nonlocal rights
        nonlocal lefts
        while nodes_list[-1] != goal:
            for i in range(0, len(rights)-1):
                rig = rights[i+1]
                nonlocal lef
                nonlocal ang
                lef = lef
                ang2 = getAngle(lef, nodes_list[-1], rig)
                if ang2 <= ang:
                    rig = rig
                    lef = lefts[i+1]
                    ang = getAngle(lef, nodes_list[-1], rig)
                    if ang > ang2:
                        nodes_list.append(lefts[i])
                        rights = rights[i+1:]
                        lefts = lefts[i+1:]
                        i = 0
                        calcu()
                    else:
                        continue
                        return nodes_list
                else:
                    nodes_list.append(rights[i])
                    rights = rights[i+1:]
                    lefts = lefts[i+1:]
                    i = 0
                    calcu()
        return nodes_list


abc = calc(triangles)
print(abc)
```

In the code above I want to get the output ((5, 12), (8, 15), (16, 19), (33, 22)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to look at.  Your code structure is kind of a mess, but that can be fixed!  First, you aren't getting any output because the function `calc` has no `return` statement.  You also have an inner function `calcu` that is never called.

Start over and avoid any inner functions and global/nonlocal stuff...  not needed.  I would start with a function that takes an origin and a list of lefts & list of rights and see if you can get it to calculate the individual angles.  That will give you the basic building block for another function to consume those outputs and make your path based on those returns.

Something like this in pseudocode:

```
lefts = [ ... ]
rights = [ ... ]
origin = (x0, y0)

def find_funnel(origin, lefts, rights):
  # use the origin and walk through ALL the lefts and rights 
  # to get all the angles as proof-of-concept
  loop through all the lefts/rights:
    print (left, right, angle)   # <-- use this for troubleshooting, then remove
  return (last_left, last_right)
```

Get that running such that it walks through all of your lefts and rights and spits out believable angles, then you can alter that function for the stopping conditions appropriate for the funnel algorithm such that when it runs, it stops appropriately and returns the "last left and last right" of a valid funnel for the origin you sent it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is still unclear to me.

Comment: While I'm running separately without def calcu() and def calc() I'm getting nodes_list updated as I want. However, I have to update variable node and then check for the rights and lefts from that particular vertice (last added to nodes_list) with updated rights and lefts list. Then I'm getting an error <    rig = rights[i+1]

IndexError: list index out of range>. I assume that it is because calcu() is not starting from i = 0 as I wanted.

Comment: I don't know what "running separately" means.  As I mentioned above, your functions are not constructed correctly.  I'd suggest you try mine (above) and then call that from a separate function that is "keeping track of things" such as the growing list of origin nodes (the eventual path) and a pointer into both the lefts and rights so you can send the `find_funnel` function a new origin, lefts, rights for iteration.  Or something similar